# connecting ssh server with private key in node js

Tags: node.js

I am getting below error when connecting ssh server with identity file in node js

**Error: Unable to read the Private Key File**

```
my code:

    driver = require('node-ssh');

    ssh = new driver({
              host: '192.168.*.*',
              username: 'user',
              password: 'password',
              privateKey : require('fs').readFileSync('/tmp/my_key')
            });

    ssh.connect().then(function() {
           /*
       some code
        */

            },function(error) {
                console.log(error);

            });

But if i connect from my linux machine, it is connected.

ssh -i /tmp/my_key  user@192.168.*.*

Please give any solution for this.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

node-ssh expects the name of the private key file, instead of the contents (example from [the node-ssh npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh)):

```
ssh = new node_ssh({
  host: 'localhost',
  username: 'steel',
  privateKey: '/home/steel/.ssh/id_rsa'
});
```

Comment: Thanks Timwolla. Now  its working, I got another error. if i execute command like "uptime" , it throws error from server.   usage: scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2

Answer (score 0):

Updated in the latest npm package, https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh/v/13.1.0
Here, the `privateKeyPath` parameter is introduced if you give the path of your `privateKey`.

Example:

```
ssh.connect({
  host: 'localhost',
  username: 'steel',
  privateKeyPath: '/home/steel/.ssh/id_rsa'
})

// or with inline privateKey

ssh.connect({
  host: 'localhost',
  username: 'steel',
  privateKey: Buffer.from('...')
})
```