# Cannot parse privateKey: Unsupported key format

Tags: node.js, ssh, openssh, ssh-keygen, ssh2

In my Mac book pro with OS Majave, I used SSH-KEYGEN generate a new SSH key for node.js module SSH2. However, I got error message: `Cannot parse privateKey: Unsupported key format`

I validated the key with ssh command, it just works fine. But not with the node.js module SSH2.

In the private key file, the header is 
`-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----` while the end is `-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`.

I checked module ssh2-streams keyParser.js. The regexp pattern `RE_HEADER_OPENSSH_PRIV` does not include my header. Can anyone help?

Comment: I found this issue in https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2-streams/issues/100 . Anyone have any idea to fall back the ssh-keygen to old version?

Comment: what parameters did you use for `ssh-keygen` ?

Comment: I tried "-o " and almost all combinations already. But it still use OPENSSH in the header. For now, I just copied the old private key for the SSH2.

Comment: the thing is, you shouldn't be using -o. See this article https://tutorialinux.com/convert-ssh2-openssh/

Comment: For updates w.r.t to `node-ssh` module refer this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366606/connecting-ssh-server-with-private-key-in-node-js/76405892#76405892

Answer (score 24):

Had the same problem, found the solution [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/939909/ssh-keygen-does-not-create-rsa-private-key/941893#941893?newreg=141e245aa38c4458a5551228ae101e66).

basically use the PEM option when you create your key:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa
```

Answer (score 13):

You could also convert your existing key, rather than create a new one (make sure you back it up before you run the following command as it will overwrite your original one):

```
ssh-keygen -p -m PEM -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

(Original answer from https://serverfault.com/a/950686)