# node-ssh user doesn't have access to ssh keys on server

Tags: node.js, ssh, server

Attempting to run the following for a deploy script in node

I'm using `node-ssh` to ssh onto a server and run a git pull, the user I'm using has a deploy key setup for this repo (it works if I run these commands manually on the server)

```
import { NodeSSH } from 'node-ssh'

await ssh.connect({
    host: process.env.SSH_HOST,
    username: process.env.SSH_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.SERVER_PASSWORD,
})

await ssh.execCommand(`git pull`, {
    onStdout: (out) => console.log(out.toString('utf8')),
    onStderr: (out) => {
      console.error(out.toString('utf8'))
      throw out.toString()
    },
    cwd: '/path-to-my-repo',
})
```

but the above errors with the following

```bash
Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ('git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n')
```

The deploy key does have a passphrase, but ssh-agent has already been launched with that identity added. If I run git pull as this user on the server, I don't get prompted for the password.

Is there some configuration for node-ssh I'm missing that will give it access to this key?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [connecting ssh server with private key in node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366606/connecting-ssh-server-with-private-key-in-node-js)

Comment: @Zak no I can connect to the server absolutely fine, but when executing `git pull` on the server, it errors